# How to unistall extension from Mangeto without access admin area?

Tags: magento

I was trying to install an extension "Enhanced Admin Grids extension" which I did fine from Magento connect. Then I realized I wanted to install the github version so I thought I was doing this correctly by replacing all the folders with the github version. Turned out it didnt work and I was getting errors when trying to login to the admin area. How can I just remove everything  to be able to login to my site again?

This is the error I'm getting:
Mage registry key "_singleton/customgrid/observer" already exists

Comment: Re-install the Enhanced Admin Grids extension package, or upgrade it, then it should fix some of the files. Then un-install it via the Magento Connect area, and install the other version from Github via the command line interface. hth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where the extension lives in your website, you can try deleting the extension's directory - try checking app/code/local/... and app/code/community/...

This won't undo any database changes though.

Alternatively, as a complete hack, you can open up app/Mage.php. Look for the following function

```
public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        if ($graceful) {
            return;
        }
        self::throwException('Mage registry key "'.$key.'" already exists');
    }
    self::$_registry[$key] = $value;
}
```

Change this function with this one:

```
public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        if ($graceful) {
            return;
        }
        return;
        //self::throwException('Mage registry key "'.$key.'" already exists');
    }
    self::$_registry[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy! Thank you. This let me login however now I am presented with a blank screen and just the Magento header. Do I need to do soemthing else? Also should I change the code in the Mage.php back?

Comment: Hi Andy- I actually just deleted my cache and that let me in! Thanks for your help.